# Can't resolve service URL in fetch on nginx server HTML

Tags: javascript, nginx, kubernetes, kube-dns

I run in kubernetes:

- a pod with an nginx server, that serves an HTML page
- a service of type `ClusterIP`

A JavaScript `fetch` in the HTML gives me `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

```html
<script>
    fetch("http://backend-service.default.svc.cluster.local")) // net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
</script>
```

However, the URL can be resolved when I use curl on the image:

```bash
$ kubectl exec frontend-deployment-75f7d9775b-pxgkx -- curl http://backend-service.default.svc.cluster.local

<expected json response>
```

Why can the URL be resolved with `curl`, but JavaScript `fetch` fails with `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

In the scenario I described:

- the `fetch` runs in my browser, hence tries to fetch from the public internet.
- the `curl` runs in the container on the pod, hence fetches from the cluster.